# Yandex.Карты: карта на весь экран - изменить z-index

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Сейчас при развёртывании карты на весь экран у yamps в стилях устанавливается z-index:500. Как правильно изменить его?

Comment: Зачем изменить? Пытаюсь понять вашу задачу.

Comment: Чтобы после развертывания карта была выше всех.

Сейчас, после развёртывания над картой элемент вёрстки сайта - плавающий блок с z-index 1000000. Менять вёрстку сайта не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Есть опция fullscreenZIndex : https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#Map__param-options.fullscreenZIndex